# Windows, copy files between different network machines using "copy" command

Tags: windows, copy

I have to copy files from one machine another machine on a local area network.

For me windows "Copy" command is working fine when both the machines are connected through the Local Area network:

```
copy c:\Tool.exe \\10.90.206.177\c$
```

The above copies `Tool.exe` file to `10.90.206.177` machine in the `C:` drive.

But Now I want to copy a file to one machine, which is part of different network.

Is there any possible way use windows `copy` to do this?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference as long as you know where to copy the file to (ie. remote machine name or IP). Can you provide a sample non working copy command (along with any error message) ?

Comment: In short, yes it is possible, if the computer on which you issue the `copy` command has (network) access to both the source and target computer via a share. However, this question is really off-topic here.

Comment: Here the problem is like, I couldn't able to do copy file to machine2 from Machine 1 . Here machine1 is X network and machine2 is Y network. Is it possible to do copy between two networks. I'm getting the error message as "Network path not found".

Comment: What do you mean by X and Y? Are the two networks linked in any way? Even if they are, there may be a firewall blocking you from accessing the other machine.